# What does % symbol in Makefile mean

Tags: make, gnu-make

I am playing around with makefiles and I came across **%.o** or **%.c**. From what I understood, it specify all **c** or **o** files. But why this work:

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $^  -o $@
```

and this doesn't work

```
SOURCE := $(wildcard *.c)

$(SOURCE:.c=.o): SOURCE
        $(CC) -c $^  -o $@
```

Both expression specify all the files. 
so what **%.o:** symbol in make file does ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Both expression specify all the files.

Nope, the first rule tells `make` how to obtain an `.o` file given the corresponding `.c` file.  Note the singular: a single file.

The second rule (claims to) tell `make` how to obtain a bunch of `.o` files, given another bunch of corresponding `.c` files.  Note the plural: all `.c` files resulting from the `*.c` globbing.

On a side note, `%.o: %c` is a GNU extension.

On another side note, you won't be learning how to use `make` on StackOverflow.  You should consider reading a book instead.

Comment: RTFM, really? I thought the point of stackexchange was to purge that mentality.

Comment: @daknowles I'd gladly purge my answer out of existence, but I can't do that wile it's still accepted. _shrug_

Answer (score 30):

The construct:

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -c $^ -o $@
```

is a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules), which is a type of implicit rule.  It specifies *one* target and *one* dependency, and causes one invocation of `$(CC)` for each target.  While this:

```
SOURCE := $(wildcard *.c)

$(SOURCE:.c=.o): $(SOURCE)
        $(CC) -c $^ -o $@
```

is a standard rule but it has (possibly) *many* targets and *many* dependencies.  Yet for all of that, it will only invoke `$(CC)` once.